# Advice for multi level csv file creation

Tags: xml, csv, nested, idioms

I have some data that end user wants in a CSV file. Each entry has a parent node and zero or more child nodes. For example, a parent node might contain:

```
Name, Id, Date
```

While a child node might contain:

```
Name, ChildId
```

So what I am searching for is a standard to represent multi-level data in CSV. In XML, I can easily create sub nodes. What is the best way to do this in CSV? I want to create a script to extract this data without any confusion about what is parent data and what is child data.

In XML this might look like:

```
<Parent Name="name1">
<Child Name="ChildName1"></Child>
<Child Name="ChildName2"></Child>
</Parent>

<Parent Name="name2">
<Child Name="ChildName1"></Child>
<Child Name="ChildName2"></Child>
</Parent>
```

Comment: It appears that each <Parent /> would be a row in your CSV and each <Child > would be a column.

Comment: So, what is your suggestion, that I use different delimiters? Please give me one example of a row in comma separated format with 2 childs in it.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you meant the same thing but I ended up using the same row like this:

ParentColumn1 ParentColumn2 ChildColumn1 ChildColumn2

Answer (score 2):

The XML could be minimized to this:

```
<names>
 <name1>
  <childName1/>
  <childName2/>
 </name1>

 <name2>
  <childName1/>
  <childName2/>
 </name2>
</names>
```

And the CSV to this:

```
name1  ChildName1
name1  ChildName2
name2  ChildName1
name2  ChildName2
```

with a JSON serialization like this:

```
{"names":
 [
  {
  "name1":
   [
    {
    "childName1":""
    },
    {
    "childName2":""
    }
   ]
  },
  {
  "name2":
   [
    {
    "childName1":""
    },
    {
    "childName2":""
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

In a row-oriented fashion, the XML could be:

```
<names>
 <name1 name="ChildName1|ChildName2">
 <name2 name="ChildName1|ChildName2">
</names>
```

And the corresponding CSV:

```
name1  ChildName1|ChildName2
name2  ChildName1|ChildName2
```

And the corresponding JSON:

```
{"names": [{"name1":"ChildName1|ChildName2"},{"name2":"ChildName1|ChildName2"}]}
```

**References**

- [Subelement Contents Versus Tag Attributes](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/element_vs_attribute.html)
- [Creating a Comma-Delimited File (CSV) with COBOL](http://simotime.com/cblcsv01.htm)
- [EXI for JSON (EXI4JSON)](https://www.w3.org/TR/exi-for-json/)
- [Process EXI for JSON](http://exificient.github.io/javascript/demo/processJSON.html)
- [Schema and Table Semantics](https://wiki.apache.org/metamodel/SchemaAndTableSemantics)

Answer (score -1):

Please check out Multi-level CSV https://github.com/siara-cc/csv_ml

It allows hierarchical multiple level data representation using CSV and also has reference implementations for java and javascript to parse into JSON and XML DOM.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this method and library